# How to determine minimum and maximum value of lateral displacement in Railway Equivalent Conicity Calculation

Tags: wheels, rail

I am trying to calculate the Equivalent Conicity for railway application by referring to `EN 15302 Railway applications - Method for determining the equivalent conicity` and `Calculation of the equivalent conicity function of the railway wheelset tread profile at the delta R function with A negative slope by Juraj Gerlici – Tomáš Lack – Marta Kadorová` [Paper link](https://komunikacie.uniza.sk/pdfs/csl/2004/02/10.pdf). I fear that I can't share the original standard as it is paid but the research paper follows the same steps. I have the profiles/ shape for both the wheels and rails. I have calculated the $\Delta r$ (Fig 4) plot (just one intersection)  and $S(y)$ function (Fig 6) . The next step is to find the $y_{emin}$ and $y_{emax}$ which represent the minimum and maximum value of y or lateral displacements respectively. $y_{em}$ is the $y$ value when $\Delta r = 0$ and $\hat{y} = \left(y_{emax} - y_{emin}\right)/2$. I am not able to move forward from here as I could not find a concrete way to find these values. I guess these values need to be extracted from the $S$ curve (the integrated one) but how?

However, I though of one intuitive approach that takes into account the delta_r vs lateral displacement plot (Fig 4). From the plot, it can be seen that the curve has few sharp points beyond which delta_r starts to increase rapidly. I guess that translates to the scenario in which one wheel has much more radius (maybe the flange) than the other wheel (away from the flange and towards the end of the tread/ rim) and if we hit that condition, train might derail. So, a safe range will be to remain within those sharp points and they can be found by taking the derivative and see where it is discontinuous/ fluctuates more (finding the outlier).

But this approach in no way takes into account the $S$ curve. So, what's the point of doing that integration? Please help regarding these questions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the approach you have suggested. Shouldn't it lead to equivalent conicity? If you just estimate something else, why wonder you did not need a step which was needed to estimate the conicity? Btw should't $Y_m$ in the Fig. 4 really be $Y_{em}$?

Comment: @TomášLétal: Even I think Y_m in the Fig. 4 really be Y_{em}. Looks like the paper chose a slightly different convention that the standard. The S integral needs to be calculated but its just that I have no idea how to use it further. However, I found a git repo which does the same and I am trying to decode it now. [https://github.com/criogenox/B-Equivalent-Conicity-Calculation](https://github.com/criogenox/B-Equivalent-Conicity-Calculation)